# Do I have to predefine type/structure if it's used within it's own definition?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have a C `cfg_struct` that contains information about how certain data is going to be evaluated. To avoid a `switch` in the evaluation code, I'm assigning the correct evaluation function to the structure itself.

```
//Some evaluation function
int eval2(cfg_struct* cfg, int*data);
int eval3(cfg_struct* cfg, int*data);
int eval4(cfg_struct* cfg, int*data);
... and so on
```

And the structure then should look like:

```
struct cfg_struct
{
  int rule;
  ...
  int(*eval_fn)(cfg_struct *cfg, int* data);
};
```

And the error:

```
error: unknown type name 'cfg_struct'
```

I tried *predefining* it, but can it be done?

```
//My "predefinition":
typedef struct cfg_struct;
```

Comment: `typdef struct` what? You need to name the structure you're making an alias of.

Comment: what is ca_cfg_t supposed to be?  Just a typedef for `struct cfg_struct`?

Comment: Also, you are using `cfg_struct` in some places, and not `ca_cfg_t`.

Comment: I wonder why my question was downvoted. Is that because I used C syntax incorrectly? Well, my question is just about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the type before you use it:

```
typedef struct cfg_struct ca_cfg_t;

struct cfg_struct
{
  int rule;
  ...
  int(*eval_fn)(ca_cfg_t *cfg, int *data);
};
```

Or use the `struct` notation in the structure:

```
struct cfg_struct
{
  int rule;
  ...
  int(*eval_fn)(struct cfg_struct *cfg, int *data);
};

typedef struct cfg_struct ca_cfg_t;
```

You also seem to have some confusion about when you can drop the `struct`.  In C (as distinct from C++), you either have to provide an explicit `typedef` or continue to use `struct tag`.  So, your `evalX()` functions require one of:

```
typedef struct cfg_struct cfg_struct;
int eval2(cfg_struct *cfg, int *data);
```

or:

```
int eval2(ca_cfg_t *cfg, int *data);
```

or:

```
int eval2(struct cfg_struct *cfg, int *data);
```

(In C++, you can use the tag name as a type name without the `struct` prefix without the explicit `typedef`, as long as `struct cfg_struct` (or `class cfg_struct`) has appeared somewhere.  This is not a part of C, though.)